# How to properly dispose socket

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

Good day, how can i close sockets of RestClient/HttpClient properly for checking list of proxy(~50000+ units) on proxy judge (ex. azenv.net) as fast as possible.
The problem is - this code create a lot of opened sockets and in middle of check i retrive only timeout error at response because of sockets exhaust (RestClient "dispose" which executing by "using" doesn't close socket at all) .

```
        string proxyFilePath = @"proxyList.txt";
        string[] proxyLines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(proxyFilePath);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var good = 0;
        var bad = 0;
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 300,
        };
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(proxyLines, parallelOptions, async (proxyLine, token) =>
        {
            var trim = proxyLine.Split(":");
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri($"socks5://{trim[0]}:{trim[1]}"));
           var rest = new RestClientOptions()
            {
                Proxy = proxy,
                MaxTimeout = 5000,
            };

            using (var client = new RestClient(rest))
            {
                try
                {
                    var request = new RestRequest("http://azenv.net");
                    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Proxy {proxyLine} is working.");
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref good);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref bad);

                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"Proxy {proxyLine} is not working. Status code: {response.ErrorMessage}");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error checking proxy {proxyLine}: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
         }
```

Here, after 300 iterations sockets should be disposed, but cmd -> `netstat -ano | find /c "TCP"` shows about 5000 TCP socket's in Established/etc status till program run (after terminate process - all socket's immediately closed)

I know, that socket should be in Time_wait or Fin_wait_2 status till doesn't recieve FYN packet from proxy-server, but can i close it immediatly if i doesn't connect to him because of timeout? (I doesn't use that proxy anymore, just remove from list).

Passing new SocketsHttpHandler into RestClient ctor and then manually disposing it doesn't help.
Or can i get a socket status of my RestClient and just wait till it fully release, and after that run another one ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to avoid time_wait entirely? That's quite dangerous.

Comment: @StephenCleary, Ye, in normal case it is, but with proxy servers which i working , i tottaly sure that they just hang up and doesn't send any bit of data. And i think for my purpose it is the last way to check a lot of proxies availability fast.

Comment: Idk if SocketsHttpHandler is supposed to close socket, maybe things changed, but from what I remember Socket remains in Time_Wait defined on windows here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay even aftter program exited. Secondary you got a socket starvation situation here, so why don't you share the httpclient between tasks, it's thread safe. just make sure to use IHttpClientFactory to instantiate, since it has all the goods built in, don't worry about concurrency, IHttpClientFactory has that piece figured out

Comment: `SocketsHttpHandler` has a `PooledConnectionIdleTimeout` property, you may want to set that.

Comment: @SilentTremor, each proxy used only once , so you doesn't want to share them between tasks.
@Charlieface, I don't know why , but even if you change `PooledConnectionIdleTimeout` to 0/1 seconds by `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)` it still uses 1 minute timeout

Comment: Move the RestClient instantiation outside of the loop. It's thread-safe and can be reused.